# How to traverse a 2D matrix of binary values and get all possible combinations of row and column mappings

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

I have a matrix of 1's and 0's and I would like to find all combinations of placing in 1 in a column and row.

The constraints for the matrix are that each row needs a 1, and the index row[i]'s 1 position needs to be less than the index of row[i+1]'s position, so in other words, it forms a somewhat left triangular matrix.

For example:

I have the matrix:

```
[
[1 0 0 0 0],
[0 0 1 1 0],
[0 0 0 1 1],
]
```

I would like to be able to find all of these combinations:

1. Assign 1 to row 0 and column 0, assign 1 to row 1, column 2 and assign 1 to row 2, column 3.
2. Assign 1 to row 0 and column 0, assign 1 to row 1, column 2 and assign 1 to row 2, column 4
3. Assign 1 to row 0 and column 0, assign 1 to row 1, column 3 and assign 1 to row 2, column 4

Essentially what I'm aiming for is a way to find all permutations of the matrix having a 1 that spans a row and column. Is it possible? I can't seem to wrap my head around how it could be done with for loops or recursion. I think a recursive strategy will probably be needed but I can't for the life of me think about how it would be implemented - any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Example 3 has both rows 1 and 2 using column 3, but your text says the a row's column must be *less* than (not less than of equal to) the next row's column. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a dynamic programming approach and quadratic time in the number of coefficients if you want to have the number of answers or in the size of answers if you want to list them.

The observation is the following : a combination assigning 1 at row `i` and column `j` is one assigning 1 at row `i-1` and column `k` for some `k<=j`.

So you can store the answer for each `i` and `j` and iteratively build it with two for loops (increasing `i` and `j`).

Comment: I’m not quite sure if I understand your proposed algorithm. Will there be an auxiliary array keeping track of assignments?